# How to make a random number only once in an android app?

Tags: java, android, random, numbers

I'm developing a "guess the number" app, it generates a random number between 1 and 10,000 and you have to try guessing, it will tell you if your prediction it is too big , etc
But when you press the button to probe your number, it generates a new random number every time you press the button.Keep in mind i'm a newbie so i'm learning java for android, but i want to know how to make this simple app.

Here's my code:

```
package com.boodle.guessthenumber;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void guess (View view){

    EditText textguess = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.textguess );

    TextView resulta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulto);

    String guessStr = textguess.getText().toString();

    int theGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);

    int rand = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);

    if (theGuess > rand) {
        resulta.setText(textguess.getText() + " is too big" );
    }

    if (theGuess < rand) {
        resulta.setText(textguess.getText() + " is too small" );
    }

    if (rand == theGuess){
        resulta.setText(textguess.getText() + " is the answer" );
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create rand as a member variable in your class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int rand;
```

initialize in onCreate():

```
rand = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);
```

remove the initialization in your guess() function:

```
// not needed anymore:
// int rand = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);
```

To make the number persist during orientation changes, add this code to your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("rand", rand);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and then in onCreate() change your random number generation code to this:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    rand = savedInstanceState.getInt("rand");
else
    rand = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);
```

Comment: It was very useful to all, @willis i will consider your tips when create a new question

Comment: What about orientation changes?

Answer (score 2):

After you generate the number you have to store it in a persistent storage, for which you have many options: SharedPreferences (which can be passed between activities), a file, SQLiteDatabase...

When the activity starts, only if the number is not there - generate it!

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to create your random number in `onCreate` such that it is only created once and then simply access that variable in your `guess` method. Modify your code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    private int rand;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
        rand = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);
    }

    // rest of code...
```

And then in `guess` remove the initialization and simply access the variable by name:

```
public void guess (View view)
{
    // rest of code...

    //int rand = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);

    if (theGuess > rand) {
        resulta.setText(textguess.getText() + " is too big" );
    }

    // rest of code...
}
```

Also, just as a note, it is not necessary to post all the `import` statements and other similar code. Only posting the code relevant to your issue is the best way to invite concise answers.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution will generate the number when the activity is started and the number will NOT change when the user rotates the screen. It will also make the activity a little bit more effective.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  TextView mResult;
  EditText mTextGuess;

  private int mNumber;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    // you find your views in onCreate once, they don't change, it's effective
    mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulto);
    mTextGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textguess);
    // BRO-TIP: Google "Butterknife".

    // Now you need to initialize the random number
    // BUT you want it to stay the same when user rotates the screen, right?
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      // when the user first opens the app, generate new number
      mNumber = (int) (Math.random()*10000+1);
    } else {
      // otherwise load the previously generated number from saved state
      mNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt("mNumber");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // here you save the number across orientation changes
    outState.putInt("mNumber", mNumber);
  }

  public void guess(View v) {
    int theGuess = Integer.parseInt(mTextGuess.getText().toString());

    // else-if is better for you: when the first is true, you don't need to check the others and so on... 
    if (theGuess > rand) {
      mResult.setText(textguess.getText() + " is too big" );
    } else if (theGuess < rand) {
      mResult.setText(textguess.getText() + " is too small" );
    } else if (rand == theGuess){
      mResult.setText(textguess.getText() + " is the answer" );
    }
  }
}
```